# Thunderbird - mark duplicate messages as read

Tags: thunderbird

Sometimes a message arrives both to inbox and to an IMAP mailing list folder available by subscription. Is there an option to mark both of them as read as soon as I've read any one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. These are 2 separate emails. There is no way thunderbird knows 2 emails are the same unless there's a plugin that I'm not aware of. Given that I've toyed with the same problem and was unable to find an answer, chances are slim it has changed since.

Your best bet is to somehow mark it upon delivery by usage of a rule.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created two filters for single mail then it will be marked as read if one is opened and read. But for your case it will be considered as read. For this you can set in filters to mark mails received to imap mailing settings as read by default

Comment: I need to leave unread mail in IMAP folders as unread if there is no duplication.